# Trigonometric Function Graphing with python turtle.

Tags: math, python-3.6

I'm trying to graph trigonometric functions using python turtle, but it doesn't allow me to multiply a float with any built-in function (sine, cosine, tangent,.etc). I want to do A*math.sin((b*x)-c)+d for the basic graphing formula. Is there a way to execute this? Thank you so much :)
Here's my current code:

```
enter code here
x= -2*(math.pi)
A=float(input('What is the amplitude? '))
b=float(input('What is the b-value? '))
c=float(input('What is the horizontal shift? '))
d=float(input('What is the vertical shift? '))
period=(2*(math.pi)/b)
y = A*(math.sin((period*x-c)+d))
t.penup()
t.goto(x,y)
t.pendown()
x=(-23*(math.pi)/12)
while x!= 2*(math.pi):
    y = A*(math.sin)*((period*x-c)+d)
    t.goto(x,y)
    x = x+((math.pi)/12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your second declaration of the y variable. You should use the same syntax as your first declaration to correct this.

```
enter code here
x= -2*(math.pi)
A=float(input('What is the amplitude? '))
b=float(input('What is the b-value? '))
c=float(input('What is the horizontal shift? '))
d=float(input('What is the vertical shift? '))
period=(2*(math.pi)/b)
y = A*(math.sin((period*x-c)+d))
t.penup()
t.goto(x,y)
t.pendown()
x=(-23*(math.pi)/12)
while x!= 2*(math.pi):
    y = A*(math.sin((period*x-c)+d))
    t.goto(x,y)
    x = x+((math.pi)/12)
```

Comment: I appreciate it. But what do you mean use the the same syntax? Sorry. I am new to programming.

Comment: Syntax is just a word basically meaning "the way you write it". In the first declaration of y you put `y = A*(math.sin((period*x-c)+d))`, which is correct. In the second declaration you put `y = A*(math.sin)*((period*x-c)+d)`, which is not the correct way to write the `math.sin()` function. -- Glad that it worked for you.